# error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist import er

Tags: android

I just starting making a new android app . I get this error when I build the project . I search on google many times but I don't any solution error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: [v7 support libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) are deprecated, and you should use [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) libraries instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'` in your app gradle( if not added already).
2. `Import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` in class and replace `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>` with `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar/>` in XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Androix library instead as mentioned in the first answer. Remove that `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;` line from your code.

Then you'll get an error on toolbar saying that Cannot resolve symbol, just click on it, press ALT+ENTER & choose import class option from the menu. It will simply import the Toolbar widget from new Androidx library.

Note that you must add androidx dependency like this in your gradle.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

with

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```